# Protocol "http" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: compiling, curl

I am trying to install owncloud, using sudo apt-get owncloud-client. I always get the following errors:

Err:1 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_16.04 ocqt562-libqt5core5a 5.6.2-1+22.1

```
Protocol "http" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

I already tried: downloading the newest version of curl and recompiling and reinstalling it using

```
./configure --with-ssl
```

however if I try `curl --version` it still lists:

```
curl 7.55.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.55.0 
Release-Date: 2017-08-09 
Protocols: dict file ftp gopher http imap pop3 rtsp smtp telnet tftp 
Features: IPv6 Largefile UnixSockets
```

so there is no https protocol listed.

I am also confused about the fact that it shows: Protocol "http" not supported or disabled in libcurl even though according to the list above http should be supported.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I would have liked to add the following as a comment, but because I d not have enough reputation, I will add it as an edit:

1. I am not sure apt-get is using curl, except for the fact that the error message 
   Protocol "http" not supported or disabled in libcurl
   arises from apt-get install ....

How should I make this sure?

2.
./config --enable-http
and than recompiling and installing did not help.

Are there any more ideas?
Thank you very much!!!

Further add-on:
If I just copy past into my browser:

https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/isv:/ownCloud:/desktop/Ubuntu_16.04 ocqt562-libqt5core5a 5.6.2-1+22.1

I can download.
If I then press install, I get the following error:

Detailed errors from the package manager follow:
apt transaction returned result exit-failed

Comment: Even though you have your own version of `curl` installed, do you know for a fact that `apt-get` is using it?

Comment: Please don't create new accounts. Read [howto merge accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 1):

It is better to first use

```
./configure --help
```

With that option you'll see all the available options and features from the software... among others, you can see

```
--enable-http           Enable HTTP support
```

which is most likely what you are looking for.